# UWP BackRequested View model Value for Media Element missing

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a media element and I'm attempting to get the Position of the video when back is pressed. I have binded Position to my ViewModel and I can see the correct value when I look at it from a button press but when using BackRequested the values are empty for the Media Element. All other values are intact.

What I'm trying to do is, when the user clicks Back, I want to store the position of the video so when the video is played again the position can be resumed if the user wishes.

```
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        this.DataContext = new MediaPlayerVM(new NavigationService(), mainMovie);

        // Pass Parameter and Play Movie
        Play((TMDB_Movie)e.Parameter);
        mainMovie = (TMDB_Movie)e.Parameter;

        // Check for Hue Lights
        LightsAvailable();

        // tie my event with back action
        SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += OnBackRequested;
    }


   private void OnBackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        if (rootFrame.CanGoBack)
        {
            e.Handled = true;

            MediaPlayerVM viewModel = (MediaPlayerVM)this.DataContext;

            // THESE VALUES ARE BLANK BUT NOT BLANK ON BUTTON PRESS
            var position = MediaPlayerElement.Position;
            var position1 = viewModel.Position;

            rootFrame.GoBack();
        }
    }
```

Any ideas on why this is happening or maybe another approach? I don't have to be updating my database within the binding of Position. Seems like over kill

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue. By testing on my side, I could get the position of [`MediaElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaelement) correctly inside the `OnBackRequested` event handle, not null. My testing app target version is build 15063, and testing on emulator OS build 15063. Here is my testing code snippet.

XAML

```
 <MediaElement Source="ms-appx:///Assets/TrimmedClip3.mp4" x:Name="mediaelement"></MediaElement> 
 <Button x:Name="btngetposition" Click="btngetposition_Click" Content="get position"></Button>
```

Code behind:

```
 protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
 {
     base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
     SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested += OnBackRequested;
 }

 private void OnBackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
 {
     Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
     if (rootFrame.CanGoBack)
     { 
         var mediaelementposition = mediaelement.Position;
     } 
 }

 private void btngetposition_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {          
     var mediaelementposition = mediaelement.Position;
 }
```

Please try to create a blank app with above simple code to test again to narrow your issue. And you can also try another device for testing to exclude the device issue.

If you still have issues, please provide your testing environment and a minimal reproduce project.

Comment: Ive justed created a sample project and it doesn't replicate. I thought that maybe the target and min version may have been an issue here but after changing it to the latest the issue is still occurring.

I used the same code and element properties in the sample project too.

I have no idea on what could be causing this, very frustrating

Comment: So Ive found the issue but it has caused another. 

In my App.cs I have a OnBackRequested method, If I comment out the code I'm able to see the position within my Media Player page  OnBackRequested method however I only want to have control over the OnBackRequested method for one page and let the App.cs OnBackRequested method handle all of the other pages.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Ive solved the issue. Instead of trying to handle OnBackRequested in my Media Player page, I was able to get the DataContext from rootPage within the App.cs

Hope this solution can save someone else a bit of time. This method is placed in the App.cs file

```
    private void OnBackRequested(object sender, BackRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        SetTileBarColours();

        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;

        if (rootFrame.CanGoBack)
        {
            // Update Media Position on page leave from Media Player 
            if (rootFrame.SourcePageType.Name == "MediaPlayer")
            {
                MediaPlayer page = (MediaPlayer)rootFrame.Content;
                MediaPlayerVM viewModel = (MediaPlayerVM)page.DataContext;
                viewModel.SavePostion();
            }

            e.Handled = true;
            rootFrame.GoBack();
        }
    }
```